# Batch interval screenshot with timestamps

Tags: bash, video, ffmpeg, video-processing, video-capture

I'm trying to make a script to batch screenshot videos per an interval with bash and ffmpeg (e.g. 1 screenshot per second)
But the problem is that ffmpeg doesn't have an option to output the frames with filenames containing their timestamp within the video (not local computer time).

I've found some hacky solutions to do this, but they're all pretty buggy, inaccurate and doesn't work in all use cases (such as videos with variable framerate)

So are there better solutions or tools to do this kind of task?

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.$1; do #define video extension
if [ ! -d "$PWD/${i%.*}" ]; then #if directory does not exist yet
    mkdir -p "${i%.*}" #create folder based on filename
    ffmpeg -i "$i" -vf fps="1/$2" "$PWD/${i%.*}/${i%.*}.%04d.png" #output screenshots
fi
done
```

EDIT:
I remade my script based on Gyan's answer

If anyone with more expertise can point out any mistakes, please do so.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#./batch_screenshot.sh [video format] [screenshot interval in seconds]
#given video1.mp4, video2.mp4, etc. within a directory, script will output the video screenshots to folders called video1, video2, etc. with the image filename of video1 - HH-MM-SS.png, video2 - HH-MM-SS.png, etc.
orig="$PWD"
for i in *.$1; do
    if [ ! -d "$PWD/${i%.*}" ]; then #if directory does not exist yet
        mkdir -p "${i%.*}" #create them
        ffmpeg -i "$i" -vf select="floor(t*1/$2)-floor(prev_t*1/$2)" -r 1000 -vsync 0 -frame_pts true "$PWD/${i%.*}/%d.png" #output screenshots
        cd "$PWD/${i%.*}"
        for r in *.png; do #batch rename all the output files
            seconds=$(( "${r%.*}" / 1000 )) #convert miliseconds in filename to seconds
            timestamp=$(date -d@"$seconds" -u +%H-%M-%S) #convert seconds to hh:mm:ss format
            mv "$r" "${i%.*} - $timestamp.png" #rename
        done
        cd "$orig"
    fi
done
```

Comment: See https://video.stackexchange.com/a/27782

Comment: @Gyan Thank you, this will work in videos with variable framerate accurately right? Also is there a way to format the filename into hh:mm:ss for the filename instead of miliseconds? Or should I batch rename them with bash afterwards?

Comment: Yes, source framerate mode doesn't matter. HHMMSS isn't possible.

Comment: But I should be able to use bash to batch rename all the output files, converting the miliseconds in the filename to HHMMSS, right? (I'll attempt this myself later)

Comment: @Gyan I remade my script based on your answer. Am I doing this right?

Comment: @Gyan Btw, ffmpeg warns that "Using -vsync 0 and -r can produce invalid output files". What exactly does it mean?

Comment: Not applicable for images - only certain video file formats.

Answer (score 0):

You could install tools that allow to take screenshots from a script like maim (if you use ubuntu you can install it with apt-get install maim).

Then you can execute it in a loop like:

```
while : ; do
    maim "path_and_file_prefix_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S).jpeg"
    sleep 1s
done
```